# S3に格納されているCSVファイルの行数が多いとDynamoDBに反映されない

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

下記のLambdaのコードでS3に格納されているCSVファイルをDynamoDBに出力しております。
ただ、CSVファイル内の18行ぐらいまでは、正常に出力されるのですが、行数が多くなると最後の行数がDynamoDBに出力されません。
原因が特定できず、ご教示いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```py
import boto3
import uuid
 
# S3、DynamoDBテーブルへの接続準備
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("Log_Report")

# DynamoDBのパーティションキーの名前
DYNAMODB_KEY = "UUID"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    # S3情報をeventから取得
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    # オブジェクト（CSVファイル）を取得して行ごとにデータを取得
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name,Key=s3_file_name)
    data = resp['Body'].read().decode("UTF-8")
    employees = data.split("\n")
 
    # 取得したデータの値を1つずつカンマで分けてテーブルに登録
    for emp in employees[1:]:
        print(emp)
        emp_data = emp.split(",")
 
        try:
            table.put_item(
                Item = {
                    "UUID"                           : uuid.uuid4().hex,
                    "01_Agent"                       : emp_data[0],
                    "02_First name"                  : emp_data[1],
                    "03_Last name"                   : emp_data[2],
                    "04_Routing profile"             : emp_data[3],
                    "05_Log in"                      : emp_data[4],
                    "06_Log out"                     : emp_data[5],
                    "07_Duration"                    : emp_data[6],
                    "08_Agent Hierarchy Level One"   : emp_data[7],
                    "09_Agent Hierarchy Level Two"   : emp_data[8],
                    "10_Agent Hierarchy Level Three" : emp_data[9],
                    "11_Agent Hierarchy Level Four"  : emp_data[10],
                    "12_Agent Hierarchy Level Five"  : emp_data[11]
                }
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Exceptionは発生していないのでしょうか？ put_itemの戻り値は適切でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

項目数が多い場合は[バッチ書き込み](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/example_dynamodb_BatchWriteItem_section.html)をするそうです。

```
# 取得したデータの値を1つずつカンマで分けてテーブルに登録
try:
    with table.back_writer() as writer:
        for emp in employees[1:]:
            print(emp)
            emp_data = emp.split(",")
 
            writer.put_item(
                Item = {
                    "UUID"                           : uuid.uuid4().hex,
                    "01_Agent"                       : emp_data[0],
                    "02_First name"                  : emp_data[1],
                    "03_Last name"                   : emp_data[2],
                    "04_Routing profile"             : emp_data[3],
                    "05_Log in"                      : emp_data[4],
                    "06_Log out"                     : emp_data[5],
                    "07_Duration"                    : emp_data[6],
                    "08_Agent Hierarchy Level One"   : emp_data[7],
                    "09_Agent Hierarchy Level Two"   : emp_data[8],
                    "10_Agent Hierarchy Level Three" : emp_data[9],
                    "11_Agent Hierarchy Level Four"  : emp_data[10],
                    "12_Agent Hierarchy Level Five"  : emp_data[11]
                }
            )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
実行しましたが、最後から２行目の箇所で構文エラーが発生しております。

[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 47)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 47
            except Exception as e:

Comment: すいませんでした。自己解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。